# EWS Java Api autodiscover does not work

Tags: java, exchange-server, exchangewebservices

i´am trying to finde Endpoints for my Exchange Server.
I use for testing outlook-autodiscover-test successfully 
and i use EWSEditor successfully too.
I simply type my email for example: firstname.secondname@ydomain.com
and both tests works fine.
When i´am trying to do the same on my java-code from github-wiki it does not work:

```
service = new ExchangeService(ExchangeVersion.Exchange2010_SP2);
        ExchangeCredentials credentials = new WebCredentials("firstname.secondname@", "mypw");
service.setCredentials(credentials);
service.setTraceEnabled(true);
service.autodiscoverUrl("firstname.secondname@ydomain.com");
```

and my trace looks like that:

> Type:AutodiscoverConfiguration Message:
>   Determining which endpoints are enabled for host ydomain.com
>
> Type:AutodiscoverConfiguration Message:
>   No Autodiscover endpoints are available for host ydomain.com
>
> Type:AutodiscoverConfiguration Message:
>   Determining which endpoints are enabled for host
>   autodiscover.ydomain.com
>
> Type:AutodiscoverConfiguration Message:
>   No Autodiscover endpoints are available for host
>   autodiscover.ydomain.com
>
> Type:AutodiscoverConfiguration Message:
>   Trying to get Autodiscover redirection URL from
>   http://autodiscover.ydomain.com/autodiscover/autodiscover.xml.
>
> Type:AutodiscoverConfiguration Message:
>   No Autodiscover redirection URL was returned.
>
> Type:AutodiscoverConfiguration Message:
>   Trying to get Autodiscover host from DNS SRV record for ydomain.com.
>
> Type:AutodiscoverConfiguration Message:
>   DnsQuery returned error 'DNS name not found [response code 3]'.
>
> Type:AutodiscoverConfiguration Message:
>   No appropriate SRV record was found.
>
> Type:AutodiscoverConfiguration Message:
>   No matching Autodiscover DNS SRV records were found.
>
> Type:AutodiscoverResponse Message: Autodiscover service call failed
>   with error 'The Autodiscover service couldn't be located.'. Will try
>   legacy service
>
> Type:AutodiscoverConfiguration Message:
>   Trying to call Autodiscover for firstname.secondname@ydomain.com on
>   https://ydomain.com/autodiscover/autodiscover.xml.
>
> Type:AutodiscoverRequestHttpHeaders Message: POST /autodiscover/autodiscover.xml HTTP/1.1 Keep-Alive :
>   300 Content-type : text/xml; charset=utf-8 Accept : text/xml
>   User-Agent : ExchangeServicesClient/0.0.0.0 Connection : Keep-Alive
>
> Type:AutodiscoverRequest Message: firstname.secondname@ydomain.comhttp://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/autodiscover/outlook/responseschema/2006a
>
> Type:AutodiscoverConfiguration Message:
>   null failed: I/O error: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException:
>   PKIX path validation failed:
>   java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: timestamp check failed
>
> Type:AutodiscoverConfiguration Message:
>   Trying to call Autodiscover for firstname.secondname@ydomain.com on
>   https://autodiscover.ydomain.com/autodiscover/autodiscover.xml.
>
> Type:AutodiscoverRequestHttpHeaders Message: POST /autodiscover/autodiscover.xml HTTP/1.1 Keep-Alive :
>   300 Content-type : text/xml; charset=utf-8 Accept : text/xml
>   User-Agent : ExchangeServicesClient/0.0.0.0 Connection : Keep-Alive
>
> Type:AutodiscoverRequest Message: firstname.secondname@ydomain.comhttp://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/autodiscover/outlook/responseschema/2006a
>
> Type:AutodiscoverConfiguration Message:
>   null failed: I/O error: autodiscover.ydomain.com
>
> Type:AutodiscoverConfiguration Message:
>   Trying to get Autodiscover redirection URL from
>   http://autodiscover.ydomain.com/autodiscover/autodiscover.xml.
>
> Type:AutodiscoverConfiguration Message:
>   No Autodiscover redirection URL was returned.
>
> Type:AutodiscoverConfiguration Message:
>   Trying to get Autodiscover host from DNS SRV record for ydomain.com.
>
> Type:AutodiscoverConfiguration Message:
>   DnsQuery returned error 'DNS name not found [response code 3]'.
>
> Type:AutodiscoverConfiguration Message:
>   No appropriate SRV record was found.
>
> Type:AutodiscoverConfiguration Message:
>   No matching Autodiscover DNS SRV records were found.

I´am wondering about first trace-stepts, which fails by "No Autodiscover endpoints are available for host ydomain.com although it works fine by EWSEditor.exe and Outlook-Discover-Test.

What can i do else with my java-code?
thx.